# Light leaks effect with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

any idea how to create a "light leaks" effect (like in the pic)

with flutter?

<strike>I'd like to create a simple background (but less fancy than the pic)</strike>

and possibly to animate it.

[edit: I've deleted those lines to avoid confusions (here and in other platforms):

- it's not about creating "a background" (no .png .jpg .gif etc)
- it's not about creating "an animation" (no flare etc)

it's just about creating a "light leaks" effect as decoration.

Take as example this [awesome fonts for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode) ]

[image]

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an image as the background

```
body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/bulb.jpg"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: null ,
  ),
```

Sorry wanted to add this in the comment but it requires 50 rep

Comment: thanks for your time, but this is not what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to shadowing in either text or container

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
     boxShadow: [
         const BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            spreadRadius: 3,
            blurRadius: 0,
         ),
     ]
  ),
  child: null
)
```

or

```
const Text(
  "ABC",
  style: TextStyle(
    shadows: [
      Shadow(
          color: Colors.red,
          blurRadius: 3
      )
    ]
  ),
)
```